# Always show file extension for screenshots

Tags: macos, screenshot, file-extension

If you take a screenshot with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> the file is saved as a .png to the desktop, but the extension is hidden.  You need to open the Info dialog and untick "Hide extension" if you want to show the extension.

Is it possible to force it always to show extensions for screenshots?

I know it's possible to set Finder to always show *ALL* extensions, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it's settable per app, only per file or globally -  unless the app itself includes that functionality, like TextEdit etc.

There is no option within Grab itself - see [The Complete Guide to Mac OS X Screenshots](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-customize-screenshot-options-in-mac-os-x/)

The extension is always there, btw, merely hidden. If you copy to a text file, email, or another computer running Windows etc, the extension will reappear.

*Late edit*
In the period since this answer was written, Grab has now gone entirely & this is all now handled by Screenshot [in Apps/Utilities].
This is now what is directly invoked by  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>  and allows GUI access to all the parameters previously accessible only from Terminal.

There is, however, still no option to always make the extension visible.

Comment: Grab does not handle screenshots taken by the global shortcuts. Grab is `com.apple.grab`. Global Screenshots are handled by `com.apple.screencapture` as part of the `SystemUIServer`

Comment: And in High Sierra if you try to simply rename the file with it hidden, then it warns you that it's removing the file extension.  However, it's hidden so how can you rename file without it removing the extension that you cannot even see?

Comment: @s -  Can't confirm. I've never know it do that & I take dozens of screenshots every day.